# Event dates in social tables

Tags: social-tables

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in the date to create event. It says in MS and I'm not sure how to convert the date/time to MS without having a date to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say milliseconds we mean a unix timestamp in ms.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time for a definition.  In javascript it would be the DateTime.getTime() function.